# Wiki software with Latex formatting?

Tags: html, latex2html, wiki

I'm looking at setting up an internal wiki at my company and I would like a system that used Latex instead of Markdown or any of the other popular "languages" to format the wiki pages. I find a lot of systems that support Latex for math or that simply renders the Latex code to an image file where you cannot select or copy the text. My requirements are more leaning to handle the basic stuff like sections, tables and math, things like tikz is not required even thou they would be nice if they worked too.

My motivations for this is twofold, it is easy for me and my colleagues that already uses latex and this might serve as a good starting point for those that still does not use Latex.

Are there any examples of wiki systems where Latex can be the primary method of writing wiki pages?

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately do not know of one. For what it's worth, if the Wiki is web-based you should consider using a non-page-based layout, so maybe run a TeX→HTML conversion and simply use the HTML (input is TeX, but output is HTML).